# How to bypass rEFInd boot loader and boot straight to Linux OS straight?

Tags: linux, startup, boot-loader, macintosh, refind

How to bypass rEFInd boot loader and boot straight to Linux OS straight?
Hi Guys,

I managed to install rEFind Boot loader and Linux Mint on the old macbook.

Whenever macbook turns on, it will go into rEFIND Boot loader screen, if I want it to go straight to Linux OS ( Linux Mint).

(Although if I didn't press anything 20sec, it will go straight Linux Mint i previously selected, I just want it go straight even without choosing)

How to bypass the rEFInd boot loader and boot straight into Linux OS? (I also want to be able to turn it on again if needed later after able boot straight to linux os)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in `/boot`, probably *(not sure about Mint)*, or else on your esp at least, you'll find a file called `refind.conf`. You'll want to edit to edit that to include the line:

> `timeout -1`
>
> - Sets the timeout period in seconds. If `0`, the timeout is disabled—`rEFInd` waits indefinitely for user input. If `-1`, `rEFInd` will normally boot immediately to the default selection; however, if a shortcut key *(for instance, W for Windows)* is pressed, that system will boot instead. If any other key is pressed, the menu will show with no timeout.

`rEFInd` is *extensively* documented, by the way. This was a copy-paste from [rodsbooks.com](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html), but the comments in that configuration file alone are more than you'll get from most other applications. You should read through it. There's a lot else you might do.

If you want to programmatically switch the menu off and on you can do so with any key as noted there, or else set up *shortcuts*, or else you might just save the config file in its current state to a backup file, modify it, then, if you ever need its behavior to revert for any reason, just move the old one back over it. There's no harm in that.

Comment: thanks @mikeserv, i will try it and let you know how it turns out. 
because i'm actually doing it for an elderly, who i afraid won't like the method of replace config file when needed.

<br/>

To clarify, the easiest method for the person to switch on and off will be a "short cut key like press certain keys"? ( and before that set the refind.conf file 1st like turn on or boot from linux or mac os etc) 
<br/>
Please correct me if i get anything wrong. 

Thank you so much for the pointers, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @KryptoBleak - i dont really follow the second half of your comment here. are you asking me if it would be easy for you to press a key?

Comment: I mean is it the easiest method will be press certain keys to turn on and off rEFIND boot loader, boot from mac or linux OS?

Comment: so... i dont know? can you think of an easier one? im not really sure what you mean...? did you have something else in mind? you can configure any menu item to be automatically selectable via some hotkey at boot time *(as Rod mentions W for Windows)*, or else you can set a simple default loader *(which is automatically the most recently updated system kernel being watched)*, or you can just set `timeout -1` and then if you ever want the menu again you simply press any key at boot-time.

Comment: okay thank you much for your answer, i will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: thanks@ mikeserv, it works as expected, I edited the `refind.conf` in the linux mint's `/boot` and set timeout to 5 sec (instead of -1 or 1), that is to give the user sometimes to choose another OS if needed without waiting too long.

Comment: @KryptoBleak - i use the very same.

Comment: a noob question, for `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/` 's `refind.conf` file is actually same the EFI mac drive, right?

Comment: @kryptobleak same mac drive? is that the efi system partition, and is the partition shared between all oses installed to the sytem? *ideally*, yes. EFI reinvented this concept some 10 *(maybe 15?)* years ago w/ EFI 1 and itanium. rather than a boot partition per os *(which was always stupid)*, one bootloader partition can call any installed os. apple was one of the first big consumer market adapters when it switched to intel chipsets. but apple *sucks* at sticking to the standard, and, as i think, they dont use the FAT esp but some HFS special thingy. rodsbooks will tell you. use the link.

Comment: Yes when we list the disk in terminal, it will show as the EFI as partition, thank you so much, okay I will read and try to understand more, thank you so much again.